# Метод, возвращающий разные типы данных C#

Tags: c#

Есть буфер в котором находится много значений переменных.Переменные записаны последовательно следующей структурой: сначала идет идентификатор типа данных(больше 20 вариантов), длинна данных и собственно сами данные. Вот в таком виде я примерно хочу получить ответ от метода (Код естественно не рабочий).

```
public var AnsParse(byte[] Array)
{
    switch (Array[0])
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            int rezult = Array[2];
            break;
        }
        case 2: 
        {
            bool rezult = Array[2];
            break;
        }

    }
    return rezult;
}
```

Есть ли возможность обойти это?

Comment: var это строгий тип, который определён во время сборки компонента...  конечно так нельзя. А почему просто Object не помогает?

Comment: `bool rezult = Array[2];` -- расскажите, как вы собираетесь из байта получить булевое значение?

Comment: Если у Вас больше 20 вариантов типов данных - какие действия Вы потом хотите делать с тем, что вернет такой метод? Если есть зависимость логики от возвращаемого типа данных Вы планируете вставлять `if` в коде, чтобы правильно обрабатывать результат возвращаемый этим методом?

Comment: @andreycha    Конечно это неправильно написано. Я образно написал и специально указал вверху что код не рабочий.

Comment: @ApInvent      у меня есть список всех переменных и я знаю какие у них изначально типы, но в буфере они находятся в разном формате (1 байт, 2 байта, 4 байта), и соответственно, их нужно по-разному обрабатывать. Из 20 исходных типов в итоге останется только 3 (double,int,string)(потому что нет необходимости в экономии памяти)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все объекты в C# наследники типа object, по этому вы можете использовать вместо var object.

А вообще я рекомендую вам воспользоваться generic'ами.

Использовать их можно например так:

```
class Program
{
    static List<T> GetInitializedList<T>(T value, int count)
    {
        // This generic method returns a List with ten elements initialized.
        // ... It uses a type parameter.
        // ... It uses the "open type" T.
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Use the generic method.
        // ... Specifying the type parameter is optional here.
        // ... Then print the results.
        List<bool> list1 = GetInitializedList(true, 5);
        List<string> list2 = GetInitializedList<string>("Perls", 3);
        foreach (bool value in list1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        foreach (string value in list2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите выдавать в качестве результата объекты разных типов, можете воспользоваться типом [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
public dynamic AnsParse(byte[] Array)
{
    switch (Array[0])
    {
        case 1:
            return 1; // возвращаем число
        case 2:
            return false; // возвращаем булевое значение
    }
    return "no result"; // возвращаем строку
}
```

Однако нужно быть аккуратным: поскольку фактический тип возвращаемого значения определяется во время исполнения, то попытка использовать возвращаемое значение неподходящим для фактического типа образом приведет к исключению во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Да `dynamic` действительно подходит, но я реализовал через         `object`, а в основном потоке просто привожу результат к нужному типу.

Answer (score 3):

ASN.1 парсер реализован на C# в библиотеке [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/). Посмотрите, как сделано там.

Я бы определил метод так:

```
public static T RunParser<T>(Parser<T> parser, byte[] data) {
   // code
}
```

Ну или если угодно:

```
public abstract class Parser<T> {
    public T RunOnBytes(byte[] data) {
        // code
    }
}

public sealed class IntegerParser: Parser<BigInteger> {
    public BigInteger RunOnBytes(byte[] data) {
        if (readTag(data) != Asn1Tags.Integer) throw new InvalidTagMetException();
        var placement = readDataPlacement(data);
        var octets = readDataOctets(data, placement.Offset, placement.Length);
        return BigInteger(octets.Reverse());
    }
}
```

Импрувменты, которые нужны:

- Заменить data[] на BinaryReader (или свою имплементацию, в которой определны хелпер-методы чтения), потому что нужно двигаться по массиву данных, откатываться назад в случае неверного кейса choice к примеру.
- Методы для возможности комбинировать несколько парсеров в один большой.